# How to reproduce Wolfram Language's base64 encoded string with command-line tool?

Tags: export, string-manipulation, command-line

With Wolfram Language:

```
In[7]:= ExportString["foobar中文", "Base64"]

Out[7]= "Zm9vYmFyXDo0ZTJkXDo2NTg3"
```

With the closest command-line software I could think of

```
echo -n 'foobar中文' | openssl base64                                                                       
Zm9vYmFy5Lit5paH
```

Why the difference? What's the best way to reproduce Mathematica's behavior?

Answer (score 17):

When you use the [`"Base64"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Base64.html) you are encoding a particular *file format*.  For Export calls the file format is inferred from the file name given, like `Export["file.ext.b64", expr]` uses the `ext` format.

When used with `ExportString`, the format is chosen automatically.  You can see here that the automatically chosen format is `"String"`:

```
ExportString["foobar中文", {"Base64", "String"}] === 
 ExportString["foobar中文", "Base64"]
(* True *)
```

To understand the output you need to understand what string is being encoded:

```
ExportString["foobar中文", "String"]
(* "foobar\\:4e2d\\:6587" *)
```

If I take that and encode it from the command line we have a match:

```
echo -n 'foobar\:4e2d\:6587' | openssl base64 
Zm9vYmFyXDo0ZTJkXDo2NTg3
```

You should think of the `"Base64"` export format as an extension of `Export` and `ExportString`, they first export to a string and then encode.

For a pure string-to-base64 you can use [`BaseEncode`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseEncode.html) and [`StringToByteArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringToByteArray.html):

```
BaseEncode@StringToByteArray@"foobar中文"
(* "Zm9vYmFy5Lit5paH" *)
```

Comment: Can you perhaps also explain why `中` becomes `XDo0ZTJk`? When using `ExportString["中", "Base64"]` I don't get that result no matter how I encode `中` and convert it to base64.

Comment: Try `echo -n '\:4e2d' | openssl base64`

Comment: @Max1 I edited the answer to the best of my knowledge.  I made the answer a community wiki so people will feel free to edit it. Character encoding and everything related has always been a blind spot of mine.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I think I also get now what happens. The string `\:4e2d` is literally translated to an UTF-8 byte sequence. Afterwards every 3 bytes of data will be translated to 4 6-bit characters (since base 64 is 6 bit). Since every element of `\:4e2d` is an element of the ASCII set they will all be encoded with 1 byte. In total we have a 6 byte UTF-8 sequence which is translated to 8 characters in a 6-bit alphabet (base64). If I find some time I might add the conversion `\:4e2d` -> `UTF-8 bytes` -> `base64 characters` to the community wiki.

Comment: Take my upvote :)

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce ExportString["foobar中文", "Base64"] by openssl without first obtaining that code "\\:4e2d\\:6587" from within Mathematica? Is there a transformation rule that can be implemented on the command-line?

Comment: @qazwsx - I'm not sure.  The person who commented before you would know better than I.